# PHP include redirect error

Tags: php

I am trying to make one page with variables on it to go to several other pages. The error I am getting is too many redirects. Here is the code:

input.php - the users inputs variable on this page

```
    <form method="post" action="/var.php" />
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
<input type="submit" value="enter" />
    </form>
```

var.php - where all of the variables will be and the redirect

```
    <?php
        include_once '/redirect.php';
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    ?> 
 //and here is /redirect.php
    <?php
       header('Location: /index.php');
    ?>
```

index.php - The main page

```
<?php
   include '/var.php';
   echo $name;
   echo '<br />';
   echo "<a href='/index2.php'>next</a>";
?>
// Index2.php
   <?php
      include '/redirect.php';
      echo $name;
   ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you got into an **infinite redirect loop**. First of all, when you submit a form in `input.php`, it will take you to `var.php`. Then in `var.php`, you redirect to `index.php`. In `index.php` you include `var.php` which has a code to redirect to `index.php` again. Therefore, you keep redirect `index.php` to `index.php` infinitely.

---

> > I am trying to make one page with variables on it to go to several other pages

There are many ways to do this. You can use SESSION or use GET to pass the variable across the pages.

Answer (score 0):

In var.php, header() is sending you to a page which in turn send you to the page where header() is. You should try setting the location differently.